# Log4j2 overhead by several Appenders & Loggers

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

How much overhead I have by having too many (~80+) Appenders/Loggers in my common configuration file (`log4j2.xml`) ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="10">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="name-one-rest" fileName="${sys:LOGS_PATH}/name-one-rest.log" filePattern="${sys:LOGS_PATH}/name-one-rest-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%5p] [%c{1}.%M:%L] - %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
...
...
        <RollingFile name="name-eighty-rest" fileName="${sys:LOGS_PATH}/name-eighty-rest.log" filePattern="${sys:LOGS_PATH}/name-eighty-rest-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%5p] [%c{1}.%M:%L] - %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
...
...
        <Logger name="cl.example.foo" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="name-one-rest"/>
        </Logger>
...
...        
        <Logger name="cl.example.bar" level="trace"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="name-eighty-rest"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I have the same amount of war files deployed pointing to the same config, however this makes repeated Appenders/Loggers in the MBean (`org.apache.logging.log4j2`).

This was made so we have only one place for configuration, but brings this repeated attributes on them Mbeans. Maybe it's only expensive at startup, but with no issues later.

I wonder of this have an impact on performance.

Comment: Seems like you should look at using `RoutingAppender` to help you reduce the size of your config file. See the [log4j2 FAQ page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.1/faq.html#separate_log_files).

Comment: @devwebcl, If your app host is a VM with mounted NAS storage, then there will be network writes and that might impact the performance. Async logging can help a bit here (make sure you experiment with `immeidateFlush` attribute of appenders). That said, try to perform a performance test and take thread and heap dumps and analyze those. Without this, you may end up in premature optimization situation.

Comment: @D.B. `RoutingAppender` depends on `ThreadContext` which basically uses `ThreadLocal`. This might not work accurately in an application env which uses reactive libraries like RxJava or Project Reactor.

Comment: @Niranjan Although the example on the log4j2 FAQ page uses `ThreadContext` you can in fact use other lookups. Please read the log4j2 manual for details.